# Extracting the parent, leaf, and extension from a valid path

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, parsing

Powershell has the `Split-Path` cmdlet which allows you to extract the Parent and Leaf of a file. In PS version 6, you can extract the extension, with the `-Extension` switch. Why this wasn't a feature of PS version 4 and greater I don't know, so I decided to write my own version in Python.

**PathUtilities**:

```
# PathUtilities.py

def parse_file_path(file_path : str):

    """
    The function a user must call if they want to parse a file path.

    It accepts, validates, and returns a tuple containing 
    the elements (parent, leaf, and extension)
    of the path.

    The path doesn't haven't exist.

    Args:
        file_path : str - A string representing a file path.

    Returns:
        A tuple containing all the parsed elements.
    """

    _determine_if_the_drive_letter_is_valid(file_path=file_path)
    _determine_if_second_element_is_valid(file_path=file_path)
    _determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters(string_to_validate = file_path[2:])
    return _construct_path_tuple(file_path=file_path) 


def _determine_if_the_drive_letter_is_valid(file_path : str):

    """
    Determines if the drive letter is a letter.

    Raises a TypeError if the first letter is invalid.

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function.

    Returns:
        None
    """

    drive_letter = file_path[:1]
    if not drive_letter.isalpha():
        raise TypeError("Drive Letter is invalid.")


def _determine_if_second_element_is_valid(file_path : str):

    """
    Determine if the second element in the path is a :

    Raises a ValueError if the second element is invalid.

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function.

    Returns:
        None
    """

    valid_element = ":"
    second_element = file_path[1]
    if second_element != valid_element:
        raise ValueError("Invalid characters in path.")

def _determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters(*additional_characters, string_to_validate : str):

    """
    Determine if the string contains forbidden elements.

    Raises a ValueError if any forbidden character is found.

    Args:
        string_to_validate : str - The string we're going to test.
        *additional_characters - To make the function reusable we accept additional elements to be tested
                             in addition to the list of forbidden characters.
    """

    # Contains all the forbidden characters in Windows paths.
    # Note the 4 slashes, because paths use \\ to seperate folders and drives, we have to validate
    # if the user entered additional slashes, two slashes is fine, but more are forbidden.
    # Example: C:\\Users\\Sveta\\\\\emp_list.txt - invalid.
    forbidden_characters = ["<", ">", ":", "/", '"', "|", "?", "*"," ", "\\\\"]

    for forbidden_character in forbidden_characters:
        if forbidden_character in string_to_validate:
            raise ValueError("Invalid characters in path.")

    if additional_characters:
        for character in additional_characters:
            if character in string_to_validate:
                raise ValueError("Invalid characters in path.")

def _parse_extension(string_to_parse : str):

    """
    Split the file path on the period, validate, and return the extension with the period.

    Raises a ValueError if the extension contains forbidden characters.

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function

    Returns:
        the extension of the file or None, if no file extension is present. 
    """

    # file and folder names are allowed to have periods, so we split on that,
    # but we're only interested in the last element, the extension.
    split_extension = string_to_parse.split(".")[-1]

    # if the string doesn't have a file extension, we return None. 
    if len(split_extension) == len(string_to_parse):
        return None

    _determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters("\\", string_to_validate = split_extension)
    return ".{0}".format(split_extension)


def _parse_leaf(file_path : str):

    """
    Split the file path using \\ and returns the last element.

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function.

    Returns:
        the last element of the file path, in this case the filename with extension.
    """

    delimiter = "\\"
    return file_path.split(delimiter)[-1]

def _parse_parent(file_path : str,  leaf: str):

    """
    Take the leaf, and use it as a delimiter to extract the parent directory, without the trailing slash. 

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function.
        leaf : str - the leaf of our file path.

    Returns:
        The first element in our list, our parent directory. 

    """

    delimiter = "\\{0}".format(leaf)
    return file_path.split(delimiter)[0]


def _construct_path_tuple(file_path : str):

    """
    Constructs a tuple representing the elements of the file path.

    Args:
        file_path - see parse_file_path function.

    Returns:
        A tuple that contains the file elements. 
    """

    leaf = _parse_leaf(file_path = file_path)
    extension = _parse_extension(string_to_parse = leaf)
    parent = _parse_parent(file_path = file_path, leaf=leaf)
    return (parent, leaf, extension)
```

**Main**:

```
import pathutilities


def main():

    try:
        path = pathutilities.parse_file_path("C:\\Users\\Sveta\\Employee\\emp_list.txt")
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        parent, leaf, extension = path
        print(parent, leaf, extension)
        # Output:
        # C:\Users\Sveta\Employee emp_list.txt .txt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module?

Comment: @200_success Since this is Python 3, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can result in a cleaner interface.

Comment: @200_success - I was aware of it, but I was unaware of the features that allow you to access the parent, leaf, and suffix. Meh, I consider this a learning exercise in writing python code.

Comment: The second to last line in `_parse_extension` is invalid Python code. When trying to source the file, Python yields a `SyntaxError` in line 155.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - This is strange, I'm unable to reproduce this error. My code runs and the correct output is produced.

Comment: @nsonline You’re most likely copying the wrong code. The relevant line is obviously a syntax error, it reads `def _determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters("\\", string_to_validate = split_extension)`, which is obviously not meaningful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [`PurePath.drive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.drive) allows UNC drives, but yours doesn't.
2. [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) implements everything you need. Which is available from Python 3.4.

Note: This code doesn't require the drive to be set. That can be achieved by checking `PurePath.drive` if it is needed.

```
from pathlib import PurePath


def parse_file_path(path):
    path = PurePath(path)
    return str(path.parent), path.name, path.suffix or None
```

---

If you're not running 3.4+ then [the equivalent in `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module), is pretty simple too. But IMO is pretty unsightly.

You can also check the drive through [`os.path.splitdrive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive).

```
import os.path


def parse_file_path(path):
    name = os.path.basename(path)
    return (
        os.path.dirname(path),
        name,
        os.path.splitext(name)[1] or None
    )
```

Comment: So far so good for a better alternative. But it's not much of a code review. And OP could definitely benefit from a code review.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What do you feel is lacking in my answer? I may be able to provide it if I know what 'it' is.

Comment: Well it’s not a code *review*. As in, you provide no feedback for OP’s code.

Comment: Clearly we have a difference of opinion of what "no feedback" is. I've clearly shown how the OP's `parse_file_path` can be simplified. Since it seems you're unable to explain your POV, and for some unknown reason limit your explanations to ambiguous statements such as "this isn't a code review", then I cannot help you. Please post an answer which fills in the aspects you find lacking in mine.

Comment: I have to admit that I’m a bit puzzled as to where the issue is. A *review* gives specific feedback about the code under discussion. Your answer doesn’t do this *at all*. Instead, it suggests an alternative. This is of course entirely valid, but it’s not a review, and it’s not feedback. Examples of specific feedback for OP’s code would be: “Well done on using type hints for the method arguments; don’t forget to also annotate return types”, or “your method names are too verbose”; or “ `_parse_extension` contains invalid syntax”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know what your definition of 'feedback' is. However this answer provides specific feedback to the code in the question. The note is specific to this question and the code I've provided also is specific to this question. I also wouldn't be able to provide this feedback, verbatim, to another question, as it's specific to this question.

Comment: “specific” as in specific to the code posted, rather than general for any code solving the same issue. This is by the way all very well established on this website, see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8410/308

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why are you referring me to that meta?

Comment: Because it supports my initial comment that your answer, while valuable, lacks the “review” aspect that’s expected. I suggest you actually *read* the linked meta discussion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have read it again. What "review" aspect is it missing? And again, why have you linked me that meta?

Comment: I suggest giving it a night’s sleep and then reading your answer, the comments and the meta discussion again.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Wow, I've asked for the same thing consistently, and you're unable to explain yourself. So you tell me to have some sleep? Wat. If you really feel my answer doesn't follow the rules of Code Review.SE then you can [post a question on our Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93339/discussion-between-peilonrayz-and-konrad-rudolph).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Were do you see that invalid syntax in `_parse_extension`? My code runs, I tested it before I posted it on CR.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the other alternative of using `pathlib`

Here are some comments on the code:

## `rsplit`

```
strings have also a method [`str.rsplit`][1] which start at the right side of the string.
```

So extracting the parent and leaf is as simple as:

```
parent, leaf = path.rsplit(delimiter, maxsplit=1)
```

## delimiter

Instead of hardcoding the delimiter in a few places, you can define it as a module constant at the top of the file:

```
DELIMITER = "\\"
```

## functions

I would bundle all the checks to validate a path in 1 function. This way you can use tuple unpacking:

```
def validate_path(path: str):
    drive_letter, colon, *rest = path
    if not drive_letter.isalpha():
        raise TypeError("Drive Letter is invalid.")

    if not colon == ":" or contains_forbidden_characters(rest):
        raise ValueError("Invalid characters in path.")
```

## `contains_forbidden_characters`

`_determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters` is a ridiculously long name

There is also no reason for the initial `_`. why would you want to stop your module users from checking for forbidden strings in a path?

This method can also be done in a different way. Instead of checking each individual forbidden character individually, you can use `set`s to test for containment:

```
def contains_forbidden_characters(
    path: str, addditional_forbidden_characters=(), forbidden_substrings=()
):
    forbidden_characters = set(r"""<>:/"|?* """)
    if set(path) & forbidden_characters.union(
        addditional_forbidden_characters
    ):
        return True

    forbidden_substrings = {r"\\"}.union(forbidden_substrings)
    for element in forbidden_substrings:
        if element in path:
            return True
```

In the last part, the `for`-loop can be replaced by using `any`:

```
return any(element in path for element in forbidden_substrings)
```

Here I also used sets to add the possible additional forbidden characters and substrings. I represented `"\\\\"` as `r"\\"`

## `split_path`

My version of `split_path` expects a valid path string. It is up to the caller to make sure of this.

```
def split_path(path, delimiter=DELIMITER):
    parent, leaf = path.rsplit(delimiter, maxsplit=1)
    *filename, extension = leaf.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)

    if not filename:
        extension = None
    return parent, leaf, extension
```

using `rsplit` twice, this method is a lot simpler and clearer.

## Putting it together

```
def test_path(path):
    validate_path(path)
    parent, leaf, extension = split_path(path)
    if contains_forbidden_characters(
        leaf, addditional_forbidden_characters="\\"
    ):
        raise ValueError("Invalid characters in path.")
    return parent, leaf, extension
```

Comment: “why would you want to stop your module users from checking for forbidden strings in a path?” — Because it’s an implementation detail that’s not part of the module’s API. It may be there now, but it may not be in the module tomorrow. By contrast, once it’s part of the API it effectively can’t be removed without making lots of users angry. I agree with the rest of the feedback, especially the verbose method names.

Comment: *why would you want to stop your module users from checking for forbidden strings in a path?* There is no guarantee that users will check any path that they want to be parsed. Rather than leave it up to the user of my API, I do it for them for free :D. I can make the method public as well as using it when I call `parse_file_path`. What would be a more valid method name instead of `contains_forbidden_characters`? I admit that the method name is my attempt at writing clean code with clear method names.

Comment: `There is no guarantee that users will check any path that they want to be parsed. Rather than leave it up to the user of my API, I do it for them for free` Which is why I offered the 3 methods: 1 to verify the path, one to split it, which expects a valid path, and a 3rd, which checks and splits the path.

Comment: `contains_forbidden_characters` is already a shortened version of `_determine_if_the_string_contains_forbidden_characters`. It is still long, but not ridiculously so